# How to customize the view of a form using the generic view CreateView in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I'm not very good with Django's `form`.

Here is `Order` from `models.py`

```
class Order( models.Model ) :
    def __unicode__( self ) :
        return unicode( self.pk )

    def get_absolute_url( self ) :
        return reverse( 'orders_detail', args = [ self.pk ] )

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ( 'p', 'pending'  ),
        ( 'a', 'approved' ),
        ( 'r', 'rejected' ),
        ( 'c', 'closed'   ),
        ( 'l', 'locked'   ),
    )

    WORK_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ( 'hc', 'Heating and cooling' ),
        ( 'el', 'Electrical'          ),
        ( 'pl', 'Plumbing'            ),
        ( 'ap', 'Appliances'          ),
        ( 'pe', 'Pests'               ),
        ( 'ex', 'Exterior'            ),
        ( 'in', 'Interior'            ),
        ( 'sa', 'Safety'              ),
        ( 'ot', 'Others'              ),
    )

    creator   = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name = 'creator' )
    approver  = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name = 'approver' )
    comments  = models.TextField( blank = True )
    status    = models.CharField( max_length = 1, choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'p' )
    quote     = models.DecimalField( max_digits = 8, decimal_places = 2, null = True, blank = True )
    payment   = models.DecimalField( max_digits = 8, decimal_places = 2, null = True, blank = True )
    work_type = models.CharField( max_length = 2, choices = WORK_TYPE_CHOICES )
    vendor    = models.ForeignKey( Vendor, null = True, blank = True )
    created   = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )
    modified  = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True )

class OrderCreateForm( ModelForm ) :
    class Meta :
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'creator',
            'approver',
            'comments',
            'work_type',
        )
```

So far I am using the generic view `CreateView` for a `Order` model in `urls.py`

```
url(
    r'^orders/create/$',
    CreateView.as_view(
        model = Order,
        template_name = 'doors/orders/create.html',
        form_class = OrderCreateForm
    ),
    name = 'orders_create'
),
```

In my template, I simply have

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Create order{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form }}
{% endblock %}
```

and it create a partial form (with no submit button) like this

[image]

However, I want to control the visibility of the `creator` and `approver` fields depending on `user.get_profile().user_type`. If the logged in user's `user_type` isn't a manager, then the `creator` is automatically set as user and `approver` will be set also set automatically. If the `user_type` *is* a manager, then that user can specify both fields to different users.

I also want to be able to name the actual labels of each fields. For example, change `Work type` to `Category`.

Currently I'm thinking the only way to do this is to do `{% for field in form %}` inside the template and run a bunch of lines like `{% if field.name == "creator" %}`. Is there an easier way than a bunch of controlled loops and if-then statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to control the visibility of the creator and approver fields depending on user.get_profile().user_type. If the logged in user's user_type isn't a manager, then the creator is automatically set as user and approver will be set also set automatically. If the user_type is a manager, then that user can specify both fields to different users.

I'd make another form for just user:

```
class UserOrderCreateForm( ModelForm ) :
    class Meta :
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'comments',
            'work_type',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(UserOrderCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        result = super(UserOrderCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        result.creator = self.user
        result.approver = self.user.some_other_field # "will be set also set automatically"
        result.save()
        return result
```

Then you can decide what form to use in view. Use it like

```
form = UserOrderCreateForm(user=request.user)
```

I think you will have to spend some time to make it work with `CreateView`. That's why I don't like CBV. :-)

> I also want to be able to name the actual labels of each fields. For example, change `Work type` to `Category`.

```
work_type = models.CharField( max_length = 2, choices = WORK_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name=u'Category')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What's "CBV" that you were referring to? Generic views?

Comment: @hobbes3 Class-based views as opposed to function-based.

Comment: So you're suggesting, I just create my own views in `views.py`?

Comment: @hobbes3 You should do it anyway. I recommend trying both variations: customize `CreateView` and write the view functional way. Chose that one that you will like more.